# Gravity Forms User Registration - disable for logged-in users.

Tags: php, wordpress, user-registration, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to modify the below code snippet / function hook to disable registration if the user is logged in.

```
<?php
add_filter("gform_disable_registration", "disable_registration", 10, 4);
function disable_registration($is_disabled, $form, $entry, $fulfilled){
//check form id and if not the form being checked status passed in to function
if ($form["id"] != 160)
    return $is_disabled;

//check submitted values to decide if registration should be stopped
if ($entry["4"] == "No" && $entry["5"] == "No") {
    //disable registration
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}   
}
?>
```

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
add_filter("gform_disable_registration", "disable_registration", 10, 4);
function disable_registration($is_disabled, $form, $fulfilled){
//check form id and if not the form being checked status passed in to function
if ($form["id"] != 2)           
return $is_disabled;
 //check user login to decide if registration should be stopped
   if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
return true;        
}
else {
return false;
}  
}
```

Hoping I can get this to work! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article/snippet I wrote to do this... I didn't confirm if this is still the *best* way to accomplish this, but it certainly is a way that works. :)

http://gravitywiz.com/skip-user-registration-for-logged-in-users/

Comment: Please listen to Aloe Blacc's [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fm660vIn8Tg) - You sir, ARE THE MAN. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a setting in the Form Settings to allow you require users to be logged in. Is there a reason you can't just use that?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you don't want to disable the entire form.

Comment: True, I just want to disable the registration function - it's actually a checkut form. The hook above is designed to disable it, I just don't know how to get it working per my requirements (is user logged in).